# Emplacing an object from its own static member func yields "constructor declared private error"

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, static-members, factory-method

In the following snippet I try to instantiate objects from within a static member function of the object (factory method). I'm putting the newly created object into an unordered_map via ::emplace(), however this fails because I want to have the constructor private (in the real context another static member function calls Place() which is also private there).

**Snippet**:

```
#include <unordered_map>

class Minimal
{
public:

    static Minimal& Place(int id) {
        static std::unordered_map<int, Minimal> collection;

        auto it = collection.find(id);
        if (it == end(collection)) {
            it = collection.emplace(id, id).first;
        }
        return (*it).second;
    }

private:
    int id_;
    Minimal(int id) : id_(id) {};        
};


int main()
{
    Minimal::Place(2);
}
```

**Compiler Error** (gcc 11.2):

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/unordered_map:40,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, Minimal>; _Args = {int&, int&}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Minimal>, false>]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:512:17:   required from 'static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, Minimal>; _Args = {int&, int&}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Minimal>, false>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Minimal>, false> >]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1875:36:   required from 'std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type* std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_allocate_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int&, int&}; _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Minimal>, false> >; std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_ptr = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Minimal>, false> >::value_type*]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:289:35:   required from 'std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_Scoped_node::_Scoped_node(std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hashtable_alloc*, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int&, int&}; _Key = int; _Value = std::pair<const int, Minimal>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<int>; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _RangeHash = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Unused = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hashtable_alloc = std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, Minimal>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::__hashtable_alloc]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:1945:15:   required from 'std::pair<typename std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator, bool> std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_M_emplace(std::true_type, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int&, int&}; _Key = int; _Value = std::pair<const int, Minimal>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<int>; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _RangeHash = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Unused = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>; typename std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator = std::__detail::_Insert_base<int, std::pair<const int, Minimal>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::iterator; typename _Traits::__constant_iterators = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>::__constant_iterators; std::true_type = std::integral_constant<bool, true>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:898:21:   required from 'std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__ireturn_type std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::emplace(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int&, int&}; _Key = int; _Value = std::pair<const int, Minimal>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<int>; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _RangeHash = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Unused = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__ireturn_type = std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, Minimal>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::__ireturn_type]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/unordered_map.h:389:23:   required from 'std::pair<typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Pred, _Hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<_Hash>, std::__is_nothrow_invocable<const _Hash&, const _Key&> > >::value, false, true> >::iterator, bool> std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::emplace(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int&, int&}; _Key = int; _Tp = Minimal; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _Pred = std::equal_to<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >; typename std::_Hashtable<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Pred, _Hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<_Hash>, std::__is_nothrow_invocable<const _Hash&, const _Key&> > >::value, false, true> >::iterator = std::__detail::_Insert_base<int, std::pair<const int, Minimal>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Minimal> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::iterator]'
<source>:12:36:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:162:11: error: 'Minimal::Minimal(int)' is private within this context
  162 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:5: note: declared private here
   19 |     Minimal(int id) : id_(id) {};
      |     ^~~~~~~
```

I *understand* this error which is due to the allocator of emplace() not being called within the scope of the object, therefore it has no access to the private constructor. But how to I get around it?

Comment: "I want to have the constructor private" Not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the constructor private. Instead make it difficult to call from outside of the class.

E.g. you can add `private: struct PrivateTag {};`, and add `PrivateTag &` as a parameter for the constructor.

(Note lvalue reference. Passing the tag by value or by a const reference doesn't work, since it allows anyone to just pass `{}`.)